# Android App uploads very small image

Tags: android, upload, photo

My app upload a photo that has been taken. But the uploaded photo is very small. How can I make it bigger?

This is my code:

```
public void maakfoto (View v) {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  



            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            knop.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
         // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            System.out.println(finalFile);
        }  
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
       // ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }

    public void upload (View v) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = finalFile.toString();
        String urlServer = "http://www.xxx.nl/testmap/upload.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int serverResponseCode;
        String serverResponseMessage;

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        try
        {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //Exception handling
        }

    }
```

And this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome" />

        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TitleBarText"
            android:text="Foto uploaden" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fotoVenster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Maak foto"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="maakfoto" />    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uploadknop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="upload"
        android:text="Upload de bovenstaande foto" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What can I do to make the uploaded photo's bigger? Now they are max. 250 x 350 pixels.

Thanks in regard!

Comment: I thinks the problem will be probably in your xml layout. Show as your xml layout which contains the imageView

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are setting the ImageView with the bitmap returned from the intent, which is a thumbnail by default. The solution is to save the image once captured to a location on your phone, and then read from this location. Heres how:

```
private void takePhoto()
    {
        Intent takePic = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)));
        startActivityForResult(takePic, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
```

The method to create the location:

```
private File getTempFile(Context context)
    {
        // it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
        final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName());
        if (!path.exists())
        {
            path.mkdir();
        }
        return new File(path, "image.tmp");
    }
```

Instead of getting the image from the intent, retrieve it from your saved temporary image:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
        {

            final File file = getTempFile(this);
            try
            {
                Uri selectedImage;
                String pathToMediaFile = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file).getPath(), "", "Image taken via my app");
                selectedImage = Uri.parse(pathToMediaFile);

                String[] filePathColumn =
                { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageCacheManager icm = new ImageCacheManager(this);
                int scale = decodeFile(filePath);
                Drawable dd = icm.loadLocalImage(filePath, scale);

                imageView.setImageDrawable(dd);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

You can then upload this image as you would normally and it will be full size.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It is to work around the issue of the intent returning an otherwise small image. This basically saved the full size version and then retrieves it. Every time you take another photo this temporary image will be overwritten. Presumably you are taking the photo and then uploading it straight away? Because if so it will upload the image you have just taken. Alternatively you can change the name if you want. You can call it whatever unique name you want.

Comment: The foto must saved in the photolibary, put in the ImageView and uploaded to the server (unique name with date, see my code).\

Comment: You can give it a unique name. Look at the line :   String pathToMediaFile = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file).getPath(), "", "Image taken via my app"); The third parameter which is a blank string in this case is the name of the image which you can set. In your example you have called it "Title"

Comment: Is there not another way to do this?

Comment: Not if you want to display the full size image. You don't seem to understand exactly what my code is doing. It is doing nothing other than returning a full size image where you are currently 'Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");' In my version the only difference is at this point I am reading the image from the saved location rather than getting it from the intent. You can still do everything else the same. When you grab the data from the intent, there is no info about the image anyway so you are not loosing data, my version just giving you a bigger image.

Comment: You are limited to the amount of data you can get from an intent which is why you are getting a small image returned. By first saving it and then retrieving it you bypass this problem. You can upload the image the same way you were before. The 'image.tmp' is just the place where the image taken has been placed rather than getting it from the intent. This way you can get a much larger piece of data.